# Share parent data to different components on page load in angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6

I have a page  with multiple components. I want to get data from one `json` file and pass that data into different components from the parent component. Currently I have passed data through service. Below are the code:
In GalleryService

```js
export class GallerysharedService {
    private productListUrl:string = '/assets/js/productlist.json';
    constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {}
    getProductList():Observable<any> {  
        return this._http.get(this.productListUrl);
    }
}
```

And In product.component.ts file, added following code:

```js
export class ProductComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor( private dataService:GallerysharedService ) {}
    ngOnInit() {
        this.dataService.getProductList().subscribe(data => {
            console.log(data);
        });
    }
}
```

Also, In Image.component.ts file, added following code:

```js
export class ImageComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor( private dataService:GallerysharedService ) {}
    ngOnInit() {
        this.dataService.getProductList().subscribe(data => {
            console.log(data);
        });
    }
}
```

Here when page is loaded, json is called twice. So, how can we achieve data in one call i.e. will get all data in product page and just pass that data to the other components(image component, product details page etc.). Can someone help me out on this? 
Is there any other way to achieve this. Please suggest.

Comment: use **`@Input`** for passing data from parent to children. Read this for more details: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#pass-data-from-parent-to-child-with-input-binding

Comment: Can we pass array data through `@Input`. If possible, can you please suggest sample code.

Comment: Yes you can. In your child component declare input property e.g. `@Input data: any[];` ... the pass the data from your parent.

Comment: Unable to get data on page load. Can someone help me out.

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this using BehaviorSubject.

```
export class GallerysharedService {
    ProductList: any;
    private productListUrl:string = '/assets/js/productlist.json';
    constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {

    }
    getProductList():Observable {  
        if(!this.ProductList){
            return this._http.get(this.productListUrl).map((data)=>{
               return this.ProductList = data;
            });
        }else {
            return Of(this.ProductList);
        }
    }
}
```

In other components, you can access the service with same code.

Comment: Hi Sangwin Gawande, Thanks for this post. Can you please tell me how I can get this data in other component. I tried in product component below code:

console.log("Service Data: "+this.dataService.ProductList);

Got undefined.

Can you please tell how can I access data?

Comment: Actually, In my above code I got data in both components but the problem is there are `2 server calls (i.e. productlist.json called twice )` happened due to subscribe. So, is there any way to get data in one call and share that data in other component.